# Sender IP/Port for UDP Socket

Tags: c, sockets, udpclient

Is it possible to obtain the sender IP and (dynamically obtained) port with C sockets? I have the following:

```
memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints); 
hints.ai_family     = AF_UNSPEC; 
hints.ai_socktype   = SOCK_DGRAM;

if ((rv = getaddrinfo(NULL, DATABASEPORT, &hints, &servinfo)) != 0) { 
    fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(rv)); 
    exit(1);
}

for(p = servinfo; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next) {
    if ((sockfd = socket(p->ai_family, p->ai_socktype, p->ai_protocol)) == -1) {
        perror("socket"); 
        continue;
    }

    break;
}
```

Which is pretty much taken from a guide (though I kind of get it?). But I'm having trouble identifying which information I would use to find out the client data.

Any and all help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: By the way, you can simplify the initialization of `hints` as `struct addrinfo hints = { .af_family = AF_UNSPEC, .ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM };` You should probably also add `AI_ADDRCONFIG` to `ai_flags` to avoid getting IPv6 addresses if your host is not configured for IPv6. You'll also want `AI_PASSIVE` if this address is for binding rather than for connecting.

Comment: I have AI_PASSIVE on the "host" end of things, but I didn't know you could initialize structs like that, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Generally you get the local address/port information with the [`getsockname(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/getsockname.2.html), but here you don't have it yet - the socket is not connected and nothing has been sent. If this is a simple UDP client - consider using [connected UDP sockets](http://kerneltrap.org/node/7491) - you'd be able to see local IP/port right after the [`connect(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/connect.2.html).

Comment: I have a sendto function further down in the code... but I'm guessing that this wont help me with getsockname and that it will only work with connected UDP sockets? Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

For non-connected UDP sockets, there's no way to get the local address. You can of course get the remote address by using `recvfrom` instead of `read`/`recv` to read packets. If you'll only be communicating with a single server, just go ahead and use `connect`. If you need to communicate with more than one server, you can probably just make a dummy `connect` (on a new socket) to one of the servers to get your local address, but it's possible (if the host uses nontrivial routing) that connecting to different remote hosts will result in different local addresses. This can even happen in a fairly trivial environment if you connect both to `localhost` (`127.0.0.1`) and remote servers.

Comment: Truth be told, I'm anticipating that these are all going to be connecting to localhost, but I need to get the "public" IP, rather than the loopback address. But I'll look into doing the connect/recvfrom, thanks.