# Obtaining IP address after broadcasting using C in linux

Tags: c, linux, networking, gcc

I have written a simple client server program in C under linux. I have created UDP sockets. The client broadcasts a message using

```
sendto(clientsock, buf, 100, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&to, sizeof (to));
```

The server receives the broadcasted message using

```
recvfrom(serversock, buf, 100, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&rcv,&size);
```

The message is being successfully received by the server. On the server side, I need to find the source IP address of the message received. How can I do that ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4129220/sender-ip-port-for-udp-socket

Answer (score 5, accepted):

for a call like -

```
recvfrom(s, buf, BUFLEN, 0, &si_other, &slen)
```

use

```
printf("Received packet from %s:%d\nData: %s\n\n", inet_ntoa(si_other.sin_addr), ntohs(si_other.sin_port), buf);
```

Comment: For god's sake, at least use `inet_ntop`.